# how can i set a special date in PreparedStatement parameters?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, parameter-passing

heloo...
I have a problem when I want to use date in my code
I have a class that named ReportService and in this class I use jdbc to connect my database and after that I want to get a report from my database in a special date.frist I write this :

```
("select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_out) = to_date ('31-jul-2013' , 'dd-mm-yyyy')");
```

and this work good.but after that I want to pass my date from my main class:

```
PreparedStatement pst =
conn.prepareStatement("select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_in) = to_date (?)");
pst.setDate(1, +++++ );
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

I don't know what I should write instead of +++++

thanks

Comment: if you are using to_date function in query itself then you should pass String of date then it will be converted to date by database, but if you are not using to_date function then you have to pass Date object

Comment: your formatstring can't be correct: to_date ('31-jul-2013' , 'DD-MON-YYYY')"); at least for oracle. But MM in the formatstring and Jul for your date can't work

Answer (score 3):

As shown in your first SQL query, to to_date() function takes 2 arguments, and not just one. And both of these arguments are strings, and not dates.

So you could change the code to

```
PreparedStatement pst =
    conn.prepareStatement("select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_in) = to_date(?, 'dd-mm-yyyy')");
pst.setString(1, '31-jul-2013');
```

But a better option would be to pass a date directly, and forget about the to_date function:

```
PreparedStatement pst =
    conn.prepareStatement("select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_in) = ?");
pst.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf('2013-07-31'));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use function `to_date` in your sql query, you should use `setString(int,String)` in your java code. When you want to use use `setDate(int,Date)` in java  code, your query should look as follows:

```
select sum(cost) from mem_Outcome where trunc(date_out) = ?;
```

and set a date you request report for.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE()` expects a String as well as the Date format. So you need to use `rs.setString()` as well as pass the Date format like you passed when you ran your query directly.

Using a *String* date:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
   "select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_in) = to_date (?, 'dd-mm-yyyy')");

pst.setString(1, "31-jul-2013");
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

If you want to use `rs.setDate()`, you no longer require the `TO_DATE()` in your SQL query.

Using a *java.sql.Date* object:

```
PreparedStatement pst =
    conn.prepareStatement("select sum(cost) from mem_income where trunc(date_in) = ?");

pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(
               SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse("31-jul-2013").getTime()));
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

If you have an instance of `java.util.Date` already, just use

```
pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

This also will work...

```
String Allocated_On = "03/20/2013";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
java.util.Date dtAllocated_On= new Date();
try {
   dtAllocated_On = (Date)formatter.parse(Allocated_On);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
   log.info("error parsing date needed: "+pe);
}
....
PreparedStatement pst =
  conn.prepareStatement("select sum(cost) from mem_income where date_in = ?");

pst.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(dtAllocated_On.getTime()));
```