# JDBC PreparedStatement, UNION Select and parameter passing

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, union, sybase

Ok, I know the answer is simple and I'm going to feel pretty dumb but...

Java JDK 1.7, Sybase JDBC driver

Code snipit:

```
String sql = "select <blah> 
    from <blah blah> 
    where date1 = ? 
    UNION 
    select <blah> 
    from <blah blah> 
    where date2 = ?";

Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

logger.info("parmemeter count: " + stmt.getParameterMetaData().getParameterCount());

stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())); 
stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while rs.next()) {

    // the rest of the code

    }
```

1. So why is the parmeter count only 1?
2. Running the program throws an error complaining: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 2.
3. If I reduce the sql to either piece and reduce the setDate() to only 1 it works just fine.
4. The SQL with the UNION runs just fine in an interactive sql session (? filled in with a date of course)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055209/how-can-i-set-a-special-date-in-preparedstatement-parameters) was very helpful. It's not the union clause that's throwing errors; it's the date that you're passing in. If you're using to_date () (unclear from your code snippet), you need to be passing a string in the query (instead of a date). Good luck!